# Styled-components suggestion props name with type script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

I need styled-components show suggestion props name
I create styled components CardHeader and add props

```
interface ICardHeader { darkMode?:boolean }
```

[image]

[image]

code is working but componen not show darkMode suggestion props

Comment: It should work out of the box and you don't even need to write the type in the string template yourself, styled does it by itself, it looks like there are some other styling issues, please check if this problem happens again with a default (not custom) element like "div"

Comment: element div is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this little lifehack

```
import { FC } from 'react';

const CardHeader = styled<FC>(Card.Header)<ICardHeader>``
```

but for good, you just need to type the component (seemd it's just any and that's why types don't work correctly) from this library and everything will work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing everything according to the docs. It works on my machine as well. The IDE may be to blame here. Does it compile from the command line i.e. with `tsc`?